# How can I implement a function that can do the comparison for dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, subset

I am stuck on a really simple problem. I need to implement a check and a minus function in Python 3 that can do the check first then do the subtraction for dictionaries.
For example:

```
d1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 7}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 2} 
result = check(d1, d2)
```

The check function compares two dictionaries and returns `True` if the first parameter is larger than the second parameter, and returns `False` if the second dictionary is larger.

In this example, the result should return `False` since `d2` has `"e:2"` but `d1` does not.

In short, I want to implement a check function that only returns True if `d2` is a subset of `d1`, which means `d1` includes all the keys of `d2`, and for each key's value, `d1` is also larger than `d2`.

The check function should able to check if `d1` includes all the keys of `d2`, and also `d1`'s value is larger than `d2`(I don't want any negative value appears in the new dictionary(d3) after the subtraction.)

I believe there is a really simple way to implement this function in Python 3.

Comment: are the keys in the dictionary constant throughout? like are the keys a-z only??

Comment: No, I use letters as key just for the example. :)

Comment: @Miss.Q If the answer below helped you solve your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries have a `keys()` method that gives you access to the keys in the dictionary. One of the nice things about the object returned from `keys()` is that it acts like a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set), so you can easily test if one is a superset/subset of the other:

```
d1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 7}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 2} 

d1.keys() >= d2.keys()
# false
```

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to determine if every value in a list is true, so once you know the d1 is a super-set of d2 you can see if:

```
all(d1[k] >= d2[k] for k in d2)
```

is true.

You can combine them:

```
 d1.keys() >= d2.keys() and all(d1[k] >= d2[k] for k in d2)
```

But the order is important — you need to check if `d1` has all the keys in `d2` first other wise the the expression in `all()` will throw an exception when you try to lookup a non-existing key. The above will return false if the first part is false without checking the second, so you avoid that error with this order.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try it now.